# How to list name of subcategory by category_id?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to list subcategory name by category_id where category_id should be grouped and show all subcategory name of that grouped id.
Please see the attached figure shown in below:

[image: This picture for database]

[image: This is what I get from my query]

In my web page category name shown repeatedly but I want category should be display one and subcategory name should be display.
For example:

```
category name   || subcategory name||
Data Management || pa , roji       ||
Executive       || lov, true       ||
```

My simple using relationship query is:

```
TeamSubCategory::with('category')->orderBy('weight')->get();
```

Comment: your parent categories in a separated table or in the same table ?

Comment: Parent categories are in seperate table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (semi-pseudo code since you didn't post any of your models or your view):

Controller:

```
$categories = Category::with('teamsubcategory')->get();
```

View:

```
<table>
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
        {{-- implode the teamsubcategories and join with a comma and space on the name value --}}
        <td>{{ $category->teamsubcategory->implode('name', ', ') }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try group by category_I'd. 
And select group_concat(distinct name) as subcategory_name

Answer (score -1):

using [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) :

```
TeamSubCategory::with
->select('*', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ', ') as `name_concatenated`'))
->('category')->groupBy('category_id')->orderBy('weight')->get();
```